# Send Message Using GCM

Tags: android, sms, google-cloud-messaging

I want to know whether it is possible for sending a notification from one android mobile to android mobile via a local server?

Comment: A link-only answer below provides [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/category/gcm/); I am adding it here as that answer is likely to be deleted shortly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a server.

Send: Your phone can perform a HTTP POST to Google's servers of some JSON describing the sender/registration ids (along with the message), which then passes the message to the target device(s). Details here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html

Note that that page describes migration from C2DM to GCM. What i'm suggesting here is the new GCM method. Base your JSON on the last example on that page:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA

    {
  "registration_id" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "data" : {
    "Team" : "Portugal",
    "Score" : "3",
    "Player" : "Varela",
  },
}
```

Receive: using Google's GCM system to receive via intents as described here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: Please provide some documentation to prove your answer.

Comment: What's incorrect? Prove your answer! (It better be good, given that I've already got such a system running!)

Comment: @Poldie, you probably shouldn't include valid or valid-looking auth keys in public posts.

Comment: @laalto  Better tell Google then - that's their documentation.

Comment: @Poldie Ok nevermind then, first thought it was your auth key :)

Comment: Whats Google's servers here? Are they documented somewhere?

Comment: @Poldie Can you share some android code?

Comment: @Brontok http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html "To send a message, the application server issues a POST request to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`" - the "application server" can well run in Android phone.

Comment: Yes, it's documented in Google's online GCM documentation. See the first link I provided.  (Spoiler: It's https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  although HTTP works too)

Comment: @laalto Yes, I've performed this post from an Android phone, a Perl script on windows/linux/solaris etc etc. It's very fast and returns success/failure immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know whether it is possible for sending a message from one android mobile to another using GCM ?

Yes , it is possible.

> Can android mobile act as server to post message via GCM?

No , You will need to use 3rd party server to communicate between two mobile phones.

Full information is available [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html).

Comment: Your second answer is incorrect; this is perfectly possible.  Your phone can perform a HTTP POST to Google's servers of some JSON describing the sender/registration ids (along with the message).

Comment: @Poldie Please provide some documentation to validate your point.