# How to send android push notification without ssl certificate

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-messaging, server

I am using only http service and I dont want to pay SSL certificate and don't use self signed certificate. there is any other way to get send push notification in my app clients. Thanks in advance.

Comment: :As per my concern in android GCM is used for push notification and it is possible without having SSL certificate.

Comment: I try GCM but it give error message. see my previous post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647660/ssl-handshake-exception-in-android-gcm-server here is link.

Comment: if u know send any link or sample code @Born to win

Comment: See my answer to the followings:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901597/send-message-using-gcm/20901659#20901659

Comment: :Can you plz let me knw if it helps you or not?

Comment: I dont know php. I am from java platform so I try to understand your code first.

Comment: @Born to win do u know any Java link(without ssl ceritificate). I can't understand PHP.